# python virtualenv that include all total python modules

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip, virtualenv, python-module

I want to ask the following Question since I am not sure if it possible ,

I have Linux machine and I installed the python virtualenv as above

```
pip3 install virtualenv
mkdir Environments
/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/bin/virtualenv project_env
source project_env/bin/activate

pip3 list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        21.3.1
setuptools 58.3.0
wheel      0.37.0
```

Now I can install the modules that are needed:

but , since I have a huge python scripts and in the future we have to create a new python scripts

then I was thinking how to support all python scripts without to install each time new module that scripts are required

so it possible to install all total python modules for python3? and what is the right approach?

Comment: `so it possible to install all total python modules for python3?` highly doubt it. Checking pypi, you find ~300k projects. You will probably find a way to get a list of all that are compatible with python3, but there is no way you will be able to install them all. Additionally, that would be a huge waste of space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you want this but here is my suggestion here.

if you want to store all your required module's name of your old script then there is one way to store list of module. the way is you need to run one command. command is

```
pip freeze > filename.txt
```

using this command one text file will generated.

after if you want to install all this module which is in your old project then using this command you can install it.

```
pip install -r filename.txt
```